# SQL How to merge 3 while statement results into one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

SQL Server management Studio -

How do I union during a while loop ?

ParentID is a Inner-relation towards ChildID

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT ParentID FROM Table1)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM FinalTable WHERE FinalTableID = (SELECT c.ChildID FROM Table1 as c WHERE c.ChildID = (SELECT d.ChildID FROM Table1 as d WHERE d.ChildID = @MyCounter))
      IF(SELECT e.ParentID FROM Table1 as e WHERE e.ChildID = @MyCounter) IS NULL
        BREAK
      ELSE
      SET @MyCounter = (SELECT d.ParentID FROM Table1 as d WHERE d.ChildID = @MyCounter)
        CONTINUE
    END
```

This code currently results in multiple row collections with containing different results, is it possible to merge everything into a complete result?

```
FinalTable 
-------------------------------
|     ID  Name  Text  ChildID
|  1  1   Foo1  Bar1  1
|  2  2   oof1  Bra1  1
|  3  3   ofo1  Rab1  1
--------------------------------
```

---

```
FinalTable 
--------------------
|     ID  Row2  Row3  ChildID
|  1  8   Foo2  Bar2  2
|  2  9   oof2  Bra2  2
|  3  10  ofo2  Rab2  2
--------------------
```

---

```
FinalTable 
--------------------
|     ID  Name  Text  ChildID
|  1  14  Foo3  Bar3  3
|  2  17  oof3  Bra3  3
|  3  19  ofo3  Rab3  3
--------------------
```

Wanted Result :

```
FinalTable 
--------------------
|     ID  Name  Text  ChildID
|  1  1   Foo1  Bar1  1
|  2  2   oof1  Bra1  1
|  3  3   ofo1  Rab1  1
|  4  8   Foo2  Bar2  2
|  5  9   oof2  Bra2  2
|  6  10  ofo2  Rab2  2
|  7  14  Foo3  Bar3  3
|  8  17  oof3  Bra3  3
|  9  19  ofo3  Rab3  3
--------------------
```

Comment: please tag the DBMS you are using

Comment: you don't need a `while` loop. Simply use a union and `row_number()` to generate the unique number across the complete result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would love to know how to loop that same table without while, could you suggest a guide or explanation?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL Server Management studio, made a edit at the top off the page

Comment: Where do `childid` and `parentid` come from? They are not part of the three tables you have shown.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'll clear that up in a minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124858/discussion-between-kapein-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a temporary table and append to it

```
CREATE TABLE #FinalTable () -- should be same structure of FinalTable 
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT ParentID FROM Table1)
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO #FinalTable 
        SELECT * FROM FinalTable WHERE FinalTableID = (SELECT c.ChildID FROM Table1 as c WHERE c.ChildID = (SELECT d.ChildID FROM Table1 as d WHERE d.ChildID = @MyCounter))
      IF(SELECT e.ParentID FROM Table1 as e WHERE e.ChildID = @MyCounter) IS NULL
        BREAK
      ELSE
      SET @MyCounter = (SELECT d.ParentID FROM Table1 as d WHERE d.ChildID = @MyCounter)
        CONTINUE
    END
```

Comment: Same structure the fields I'm collecting? 


Example : CREATE TABLE #FinalTable (int, string, string)

Comment: I figured it out, This enabled the SQL statement to become 30ms Faster then before ( 32 ms before ) now 2, Thanks for that !

Comment: I choose to use 
'DECLARE FinalTable TABLE (ID int, Name Varchar(50), DataTypeID int)'

and finish with a  'SELECT * FROM FinalTable'